# Commercial control suite for Windows Forms and WPF: which can be recommended?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, controls

At the moment we are discussing to buy a **commercial control/component suite** for **Windows Forms** and **WPF**. There are several suppliers on the market, like **Telerik**, **DevExpress**, **VIBlend** and others. Which of them would you recommend? What are the differences? Which suites have the best price-performance ratio? Which are easy to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WE are using [Xceed](http://xceed.com/) and [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/)

Both of them are actively developed.
Xceed has a very active community and well documented products.

**Edit:**

Before selecting one lib ensure what you need. Research forums on each lib and check how other users were/weren't able to solve their issues. Control libraries are nice in use in standard scenarios, but if you want some more sophisticated solution you will need to dig into forums/blogs about the lib you have taken. That's why **community** is so important.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the Telerik suite.  They can be rather bulky but they are feature-rich.

Answer (score 1):

One true source for this kind of information: 
http://www.componentsource.com/features/net-winform-controls/index.html

Check prices, comparison, reviews...

My comment:
-1 for Telerik (memory issues, really really bulky)
+1 DevExpress (easy)
+1 ComponentOne (easy)
+1 Ingragistics (easy)